# tree command how to omit too many subfolders?

Tags: tree

I want to preview the structure of a folder with `tree -d`. However, some subfolder has too many subfolders, which prevent me to preview the whole tree at a glance, so I want a argument such as `--maxSubfolders 8`, which makes the leftover displays an ellipsis.

```bsh
tree -d --maxSubfolders 3
```

outputs

> a
> b
> c
> ...

Comment: I know `-L 3` limits the depth of displayed tree. What I want is to limit the width of each level.

Comment: You could use [broot](https://dystroy.org/broot/) instead of tree.

Comment: `--filelimit #`
              Do not descend directories that contain more than `#` entries.